# How to post parameters in a ColdFusion web service api?

Tags: iphone, ios, coldfusion

My application web service is written in ColdFusion and returns a url for login. So how can I pass parameters in that url and get a response from the ColdFusion web service api?

Comment: Hayden - sorry, more info needed :)  Your "application webservice" returns a "URL" For login? and then you use that url to login to a service? Not sure if I follow you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand your question.  But in general, if you have a cfc you are calling named:

http://www.mysite.com/login.cfc

That cfc is going to have functions inside of it. *IF* at least one of the functions is set to access = remote like say this one:

```
<cffunction name="login"  access="remote">
    <arguments name="username">
    <arguments name="password"> 
    <cfset result = checkLogin(username, password)>
    <cfreturn result>
</cffunction>
```

*IF* there is a remotely available function in that cfc you can call it from the browser URL like this:

http://www.mysite.com/login.cfc?method=login&username=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD

The url needs to method= and a corresponding function name that allows remote access, then you can just pass any required arguments.

Is this code you wrote or just a cfc you are trying to connect to?

Tim